# Extend data/shrink window for pct_change at end of series

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sliding-window

I am trying to calculate percent change (for periods greater than 1) with a shrinking window effect at the end of a series.

The following example does not produce the desired result:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    labels = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B']
    prices = [62, 55, 55, 74, 31, 77, 20, 21, 25, 30, 21, 35, 66, 12, 1, 2, 4]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'label':labels,'price': price}, columns = ['label', 'price'])
    df['price_chg'] = df.groupby('label')['price'].transform(lambda x: x.pct_change(3, fill_method=None).shift(-3))
    df = df.iloc[np.lexsort((df.index, df['label'].values))]
```

df

```
        label   price   price_chg
    0   A       62      0.193548
    1   A       55      -0.436364
    2   A       55      -0.636364
    3   A       74      NaN
    4   A       31      NaN
    6   A       20      NaN
    5   B       77      -0.727273
    8   B       25      0.400000
    9   B       30      -0.866667
    10  B       21      NaN
    11  B       35      NaN
    16  B       4       NaN
    7   C       21      -0.952381
    12  C       66      -0.969697
    13  C       12      NaN
    14  C       1       NaN
    15  C       2       NaN
```

The desired result:

```
        label   price   price_chg
    0   A       62      0.193548
    1   A       55      -0.436364
    2   A       55      -0.636364
    3*  A       74      -0.729730
    4*  A       31      -0.354839
    6   A       20      NaN
    5   B       77      -0.727273
    8   B       25      0.400000
    9   B       30      -0.866667
    10* B       21      -0.809523
    11* B       35      -0.885714
    16  B       4       NaN
    7   C       21      -0.952381
    12  C       66      -0.969697
    13* C       12      -0.833333
    14* C       1       1.000000
    15  C       2       NaN
```

In the desired result, the percent change calculation continues past index 2 for group 'A'. Thus the values for index 3 and index 4 are calculated as:

```
    df.loc[3,['price_chg']] = float(df.loc[6,['price']] / df.loc[3,['price']] - 1)
    -0.729730
    df.loc[4,['price_chg']] = float(df.loc[6,['price']] / df.loc[4,['price']] - 1)
    -0.354839
```

similarly for the values at index 10 and 11 (label 'B'):

```
    df.loc[10,['price_chg']] = float(df.loc[16,['price']] / df.loc[10,['price']] - 1)
    -0.809523
    df.loc[11,['price_chg']] = float(df.loc[16,['price']] / df.loc[11,['price']] - 1)
    -0.885714
```

and so-forth for label 'C'.

I was thinking that a custom sliding window function, or a way to repeat the last value of the series the required amount of times (virtual extension) could be done, but I am unfamiliar with how to accomplish this. Since I am working with a large pct_change() period and a lot of data, I am thinking that a custom sliding window approach may be quicker and thus more preferable to extending the series.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main problem is that calculating the percentage and then doing the shift makes that the values that are at the extremes are filled with `NaN`.

One solution for your problem can be to calculate the percentage using `pandas.DataFrame.shift`:

```
df['price_chg'] = df.groupby('label')['price'].transform(
                  lambda x: (x.shift(-3).ffill(limit=2)-x)/x)
```

`x.shift(-3).ffill(limit=2)`: In this expression we are shifting the rows backwards and filling the nan values appearing with the last value available for the label. Our maximum fill will be of two rows, since as we are forward filling, that last row would correspond to a period=0 (pct_change =0) and that is not desired.

Then `df` will be:

```
> df

   label  price  price_chg
0      A     62   0.193548
1      A     55  -0.436364
2      A     55  -0.636364
3      A     74  -0.729730
4      A     31  -0.354839
6      A     20        NaN
5      B     77  -0.727273
8      B     25   0.400000
9      B     30  -0.866667
10     B     21  -0.809524
11     B     35  -0.885714
16     B      4        NaN
7      C     21  -0.952381
12     C     66  -0.969697
13     C     12  -0.833333
14     C      1   1.000000
15     C      2        NaN
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It didn't occur to me to use ffill with the limit argument. Thanks!